# how to deal with error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> in c++

Tags: c++

i've got a problem with find_if() in the method remv() of HC class. This method is intended to remove a ptr from the vector humans
here is my code:

```
class H {
protected:
    //string name = "null";
public:
    virtual string getName() = 0;
};

class P : public H {
    string name;
public:
    P() {}
    P(string n) : name(n) {}

    string getName() {return this->name;}
};

class HC {
public:
    vector< unique_ptr<H> > humans;
    void add(unique_ptr<H> h) { this->humans.push_back(move(h)); }
    void display() { for(auto& i: humans) cout << i->getName(); }
    void remv(){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        auto it = find_if(humans.begin(), humans.end(), [&s](unique_ptr<H> h) {return h->getName() == s;}); 
        humans.erase(humans.begin());
    }
};
```

once find_if() is put in remv() i see the following:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = H; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
```

could you please explain me what is wrong with my code? I guess it is related with move semantics

Comment: Unique pointers cannot be copied. That's what unique means. Pass a reference here `[&s](unique_ptr<H>& h)`

Comment: Unrelated, but since you'll be deleting via a base class pointer, you need a `virtual` destructor in the base class.

Comment: For future reference omitting the few lines of headers really makes it annoying to copy/paste the code to replicate the issue.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks, next time i won'f forget about headers. Sorry.

Comment: @TedLyngmo is it necessary if i use unique_ptr?

Comment: @Caparso Absolutely. The `unique_ptr` will simply do a `delete` (or `delete[]`) on the base class pointer. It's not like a `shared_ptr` which stores the deleter for the object too, not only a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_ptr<H> h` - it attempts to copy a not copyable object. The error message informs you about the removed copy constructor. You should use a const reference `const unique_ptr<H>& h` if you don't want to copy and modify an argument.

Other useful changes.
`virtual string getName() = 0;` to `virtual string getName() const = 0;`.
`string getName()` to `string getName() const override`.